# Bind Address missing in my.cnf in MYSQL centos

Tags: mysql, centos, my.cnf

I have hit a problem, when I edit the `my.cnf` for MySQL, the `bind-address` line is not in the file.

Here is the content of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: So what is the problem? Can you connect to mysql server? Try to add this line manually.

Comment: Yes I can connect to the mysql server. I am actually implementing the master slave relation between the two servers

Comment: So try to add this manyally 

bind-address    = 12.23.45.67

Comment: Hi Megha, I hope you got your answer. Now, i got stuck same error. 
In 'my.cnf' file, where can i add 'bind-address' ??

Answer (score 6):

Just add these lines to `mysqld` section depending on your preferences:

1. If you want it to only be accessible through localhost:

   `bind-address=127.0.0.1`
2. If you want it to be accessible through an interface which assigned an IP address of XXX.YYYY.WWW.ZZZZ:

   `bind-address=XXX.YYYY.WWW.ZZZZ`
3. If you want it to be accessible through all interfaces available, This is **not recommended** except when you properly configured your firewall for it:

   `bind-address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: I have applied 3rd option but still not connecting. How can I check firewall?

Comment: The file has `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` which means you've connecting locally via UNIX socket. Remove that line first.